# One of the postgres containers stops as soon as it starts

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

I’m currently working in a big app which has a parent folder with the docker.compose file calling other docker-compose files in sub folders which are the different modules of the app.

Everything works in other computers but in my mac I started having an issue trying to install everything. One of the containers is exiting as soon it starts when I run `docker-compose up -d` in the parent folder.

They are 9 containers but only 8 remain running. The one stopping is one of the three postgres containers.
It’s not the code, since it works in other computers including my laptop at work (all ubuntu) and I cannot modify it since it probably would affect the rest of the team.

I already removed all containers, images and the entire project and reinstall and built everything and nothing. Again, this code works as expected in other Ubuntu computers, this is a Mac.

parent docker-compose file

```
db_module_1:
    extends:
      file: module_1/docker-compose.yml
      service: db_module_1
    ports:
     - "5432:5432"
```

child docker-compose file

```
db_module_1:
  image: postgres:9.6.3
  environment:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: db1
    POSTGRES_DB: db1
    POSTGRES_USER: db1
  volumes:
   - data_module_1:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  networks:
   - appnet
```

I tried `docker start <container id>` and nothing, the container exits as soon as it start.
Also tried `docker start -a <container-id>` and I get some error:

```
CONTEXT:  line 84 of configuration file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf"
FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
LOG:  database system is shut down
```

but I don't know if this is pointing to the source of the problem.

I expect that postgres container to remain running as the other do. Instead this postgres container exits as soon as it starts.

Comment: Carefully read the log of your terminal, it's possible that you're having a disk space issue. Remove all the containers `docker stop $(docker ps -aq)` then `docker rm $(docker ps -aq)` and all the images `docker rmi $(docker images -q) --force` and then rebuild `docker-compose up --build`.

Comment: hi  dmitryro, thanks for your answer. As i explained I already did that, which log do you mean?. My hard drive isn't out of space, I only used a quarter of its capacity.

Comment: I mean when you run `docker-compose up` in the terminal, you can see what's going on and why your volume is not mounted as expected or why postgres is not getting access. Also possible your permissions are not set up - if `data_module_1` is a legitimate volume in your `volumes` block, postgres service should get access to it, as docker-compose overrides what's in Dockerfile, if something is set there also.

Comment: What's on line 84 of pg_hba.conf?